# Table Schema for storing various dates of availability

Tags: mysql, database

First off, I am new to database design so apologies for use of incorrect terminology.

For a university assignment I have been tasked with creating the database schema for a website. Part of the website a user selects the availability of hosting an event but the event can be at any time so for example from `12/12/2015 - 15/12/2015` and `16/01/2016 - 22/12/2016` and also singular dates such as `05/01/2016`. They also have the option of having the event all the time

So I am unsure of how to store all these kind of variables in a database table without using a lot of rows. The example below is a basic one that would store each date of availability but that is a lot of records and that is just for one event. Is there a better method of storing these values or would this be stored elsewhere, outside of a database.

```
calendar_id | event_id | available_date
---------------------------------------
     492    |    602   | 12/12/2015
     493    |    602   | 13/12/2015
     494    |    602   | 14/12/2015
     495    |    602   | 15/12/2015
     496    |    602   | 05/01/2016
     497    |    602   | 16/01/2016
     498    |    602   | 17/01/2016
```

etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This definitely requires a database. I don't think you should be concerned about the number of records in a database... that is what databases do best. However, from a university perspective there is something called [Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). In simple terms normalization is about minimizing data repetition.

### Steps to design a schema

#### Identify entities

As the first step of designing a database schema I tend to identify all the entities in the system. Looking at your example I see (1) `Events` and (2) `EventTimes` (event occurrences/bookings) with a one-to-many relation since one `Event` might have multiple `EventTimes`. I would suggest that you keep these two entities separate in the database. That way an `Event` can be extended with more attributes/fields without affecting its `EventTimes`. Most importantly you can add many `EventTimes` on an `Event` without repeating all the event's fields (which would be the case if you use a single table).

#### Identify attributes

The second step for me is to identify all the attributes/fields of each entity. Additionally, I always suggest an auto-increment `id` in every table to uniquely identify a row.

#### Identify constraints

This might be a bit more advanced, but most of the times you have constraints on what is acceptable data values or what uniquely identifies a row in real-life. For example, the `Event.id` might identify the row in the database but you might also require that each event has a unique `title`

### Example schema

This has to be adjusted to the assignment or, in a real application, to the system's requirements

#### Events table

- id int auto-increment
- title varchar unique: Event's title
- always_on boolean/enum: If 'Y' then the event is on all the time
- ... more fields here ... (category, tags, notes, description, venue,...)

#### EventTimes

- id int auto-increment
- event_id foreign key pointing to `Event.id`
- start_datetime datetime or int (int if you go for a unix timestamp)
- end_datetime : as above
- ... more fields again... (recursion below is a hard one! avoid it if you can)
- recursion enum/int : Is the event repeated? Weekly, Montly, etc
- recursion_interval int: Every x days, months, years, etc

A note on date/times, as a rule of thumb whenever you deal with dates and times in a database, always store them in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC) format. You probably don't want/need to mess with timezones in an assignment... but keep it in mind.

#### Possible extensions to the example

Designing a complete system one might add the tables: Venues, Organizers, Locations, etc... this can go on forever! I do try to think of future requirements when designing but do not over do it cause you end up with a lot of fields that you don't use and increased complexity.

### Conclusion

Normalization is something you have to keep in mind when designing a database, however you can see that the more you normalize your schema the more complex will become your `select`s and `join`s. There is a trade-off there between data efficiency and query efficiency... That is the reason I used "from a university perspective" earlier. In a real-life system with complex data structures (for example graphs!) you might require to under-normalize the tables to make your queries more efficient/faster or easier. There are other approaches to deal with such issues (functions in the database, temporary/staging tables, views, etc) but always depends on the specific case.

Another really useful thing to keep in mind is: Requirements always change! Design your databases taking as granted that fields will be added/removed, more tables will be added, new constraints will appear, etc and thus make it as extensible and easy to modify as possible... (now we are scratching a bit "Agile" methodologies)

I hope this helps and does not confuse things more. I am not a DBA per-se but I have designed a few schemes. All the above come from experience rather than a book and they may not be 100% accurate. Definitely not the only way to design a database... its kind of an art this job :)

Comment: This is a brilliant answer, with a great explanation to boot, thank you.